# Hypergraph examples for laymen

Tags: examples-counterexamples, hypergraphs

When I try and explain graph theory to my non-mathematician friends, I usually resort to motivating the idea through things like computer networks or neurons connected by synapses, but I don't have a good "real world" example to motivate hypergraphs.  I'd love to hear some of your ideas!

Comment: Maybe you can get some ideas here: [Real world applications of hypergraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14767284), [What are the Applications of Hypergraphs](https://mathoverflow.net/q/13750). Of course, not all applications are good motivating examples, but I think most good motivating examples come from applications. Two examples I found from there: co-authorship networks, chemical reaction networks (as directed hypergraphs).

Comment: Perhaps the graph with vertices as people and hyperedges as sets of people who get along together.